# Django internationalization language codes

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-views, django-i18n

Where can I find list of languages and language_code like this.

```
(Swedish,sv)
(English,en)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Wiki:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes

Comment: Not all of these language codes are supported. See file django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO for the master list.

Comment: There is no guarantee that what Django has actually implemented is exactly in line with this list, which is not maintained by Django.

Comment: http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html

Comment: https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/conf/global_settings.py#L56

Answer (score 68):

If you want something you can use from within django, try:

```
from django.conf import settings
```

this will be in the format above, making it perfect for assignment in one of your models choices= fields. (i.e. `user_language = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=settings.LANGUAGES)`)

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('ar', gettext_noop('Arabic')),
    ('bg', gettext_noop('Bulgarian')),
    ('bn', gettext_noop('Bengali')),
    etc....
    )
```

## Note about using settings:

[Note that django.conf.settings isn’t a module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code)

Comment: Added bonus to this method: since the gettext_noop() is a lazy lookup, the language names will be translated based upon your user's locale at template render time. Meaning an english user will see "French" but a french user will see "Francais"

Comment: is there any reference Pages for the above languages ..

Comment: http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/conf/global_settings.py will give you the full list of languages django supports out of the box, and http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#languages gives you an overview of usage. Hope this helps.

Comment: `max_length` should be 5, there is a dash in country specific languages, e.g. `es-mx`

Comment: @Kimvais: 'sr-latn' has 7 characters

Comment: The list of languages in this setting is not the same as the list of values accepted by the LANGUAGE_CODE setting. An example is the 'en-us' default value, that doesn't exist in the LANGUAGES global setting.

Answer (score 27):

Previous answers mention only getting `LANGUAGE` from *settings.py*, hovewer there is a big chance that this variable will be overwritten. So, you can get the full list from [`django.conf.global_settings.LANGUAGES`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/global_settings.py#L56-L145)

```
from django.db import models

from django.conf.global_settings import LANGUAGES

class ModelWithLanguage(models.Model):
    language = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=LANGUAGES)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from django.conf import settings

 #note settings is an object , hence you cannot import its contents

 settings.configure()

 #note LANGUAGES is a tuple of tuples

 lang_dict = dict(settings.LANGUAGES)

 #use lang_dict for your query.

 print lang_dict['en']
```

Regards

sachin

Answer (score 0):

I understood from [Django Project](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/) that you can only use a dummy gettext function:

> If you define a custom LANGUAGES setting, as explained in the previous bullet, it's OK to mark the languages as translation strings -- but use a "dummy" `ugettext()` function, not the one in `django.utils.translation`. You should never import `django.utils.translation` from within your settings file, because that module in itself depends on the settings, and that would cause a circular import.".

It took me some time to find the solution, but I finally got it; the choices of the model field needs to have a tuple with real gettext functions, with a lambda function the dummy's can be wrapped in the real gettext functions as follows:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

language = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=map(lambda (k,v): (k, _(v)), settings.LANGUAGES), verbose_name=_('language'))
```