# What Languages does Django support? I can't find a comprehensive list

Tags: django, internationalization, translation

Ok so I'm writing an international Django app, And the docs for doing localization are great except I can't seem to find a complete list of the supported languages anywhere. Where are they? What I really want to do is use the list to populate choices on a model, so if there is a way to get this programmatically that would be best.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for this list? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale If so, please update your question to get rid of ALL UPPER CASE LETTERS.  THEY MAKE YOUR QUESTION LOOK STUPID.

Comment: No that would be a definition of what a Locale is. I was looking for a list that has the locales Django supports and the code for each of them.

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201018/django-language-codes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cleaning up the pieces of answers:

```
from django.conf.global_settings import LANGUAGES

class MyModel(models.Model)
    my_field = CharField(max_length=7, choices=LANGUAGES)
```

and you can see the code directly: [global_settings](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/global_settings.py) and [locale/__init__.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/locale/__init__.py)

For more complete instructions on how to build a more extensive list, check out the [W3C Language Tag Page](http://www.w3.org/International/articles/language-tags/)

Answer (score 6):

Straight from the source. All languages Django (trunk) offers translations for.

http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/conf/locale

Answer (score 3):

This may be what you're looking for:

http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.2.4/django/conf/locale

Comment: I think this is close to what you're wanting: http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.2.4/django/conf/global_settings.py#L43

Comment: Hi RJ, sorry for the downvote, but I do so with the good intentions of keeping the content here on SO fresh.  The link you refer to is dead, so its sorta useless =/

Comment: @mkoistinen you could provide an up-to-date link yourself, you know. The guy can hardly be held accountable for bit rot.

Comment: @nadavwr True, this is why I made sure to let him know that it wasn't personal. The fact remains, as time continues to march on, this is still the top-voted answer for this question, and it is 100% useless today. If others downvoted responses that are currently useless and upvoted those that are more useful today, then SO will become a more useful place for everyone, right? Also, since linkrot is a fact of life for everyone, perhaps the utility of this answer shouldn't rely 100% on a single link? I remain justified in my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Instructions within django's settings file itself.

http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html